# Replace only the first character of a string with str_replace?

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I'm trying to replace only the first character of a string, but it isn't working, it replaces all the "0" on the string, here's my code:

```
$mes2 = str_replace('0', '', $mes[0]);
```

I want to replace the first character only if its a 0, example:

> 07 becomes 7

I don't want to replace all the time, example:

> 11 becomes 1, i don't want it.

I also tried this way, but it didn't work the way i want, because it's replacing also the second character if it's 0, like 10 becomes 1.

```
$mes2 = preg_replace('/0/', '', $mes, 1);
```

Comment: Take a look at [substr_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)

Comment: echo substr_replace("String", "a", 0, 1);

Answer (score 31, accepted):

OK, based on refinements to your question, what you probably want is `ltrim`.

```
$out = ltrim($in, "0");
```

This will strip all leading zeroes from `$in`. It won't remove zeroes from anywhere else, and it won't remove anything other than zeroes. Be careful; if you give it "000" you'll get back "" instead of "0".

You could use typecasting instead, as long as `$in` is always a number (or you want it to result in 0 if it isn't):

```
$out = (int) $in;
```

- 007 becomes 7
- 000 becomes 0
- 100 stays as 100
- 456 stays as 456
- 00a becomes 0
- 56a becomes 0
- ab4 becomes 0
- -007 becomes -7

...etc.

Now, in the unlikely event that you **only want to replace the first 0**, so for example "007" becomes "07", then your latest attempt mentioned in your question is almost there. You just need to add a "caret" character to make sure it only matches the start of the string:

```
$out = preg_replace('/^0/', '', $in);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `substr`:

```
$mes2 = substr($mes, 1);
```

This will *remove* the first character, which is what it looks like you're trying to achieve. If you want to replace it with something, use this:

```
$mes2 = $new_char . substr($mes, 1);
```

## Edit

I may have misread your question - if `$mes[0]` is the original string, use `$mes[0]` in place of `$mes` above.

Comment: But you don't know if the first character really was a 0 which you wanted to replace.

Comment: I don't believe that's what the OP wants to achieve. I think the 0 in the question is looking for the character at index 0, not a physical "0".

Comment: I want to replace only if the first character is a 0, example: 07 become 7, this code  would replace all the time, like 11 would become 1, i don't want it.

Comment: This is the correct answer to a different question.

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = '1ere is the solution';
echo preg_replace('/1/', 'h', $str, 1); // outputs 'here is the solution'
```

Comment: The OP has clarified that they do not want to replace the 2nd character (or later).  This solution doesn't meet the brief.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in PHP can be accessed just like array

```
<?php
$var = "test";
$var[0] = "1";
var_dump($var);
?>
```

Will output `string(4) "1est"`

Comment: This is the correct answer to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that like this:

```
$mes2 = "07 test subject";
if($mes2['0']=='0') { $mes2['0']=''; }
echo $mes2;
```

This will output:

```
7 test subject
```

Answer (score -1):

You may simple use `$mes[0] = '';` or if you need specific substitution something like `$mes[0] = $mes[0] == '<replaced character>' ? '' : $mes[0];`

Answer (score -1):

This is how I would have done it:

```
$mes2 = substr_replace($mes[0],'',strpos($mes[0], '0'),1);
```

Comment: I don't like the look of the loose usage of `strpos()`.  This looks like, at best, the correct answer to a different question.